# can operation reorder to before memory_order_release?

Tags: c++, atomic

Can `y.store` reorder to before `x.store`? Because the standard said any atomic operation happen before `memory_order_release` cannot be reorder to after `memory_order_release`, but didnt state any operation happen after `memory_order_release` cannot reorder to before `memory_order_release`.

If i can happen, then the Listing 5.12 example from c++ concurrency in action book is wrong?

```
std::atomic<bool> x,y;
std::atomic<int> z;
void write_x_then_y()
{
 x.store(true,std::memory_order_relaxed);
 std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release);
 y.store(true,std::memory_order_relaxed);
}
```

Comment: See the note [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_thread_fence#Notes). A fence acts a bit stronger than an atomic operation of the same memory order, effectively preventing any stores below the fence moving above stores above the fence. (I'm just a couple of chapters ahead of you in the same book - the atomic operations chapter is definitely a bit mind-bending).

Comment: @BoBTFish yes the atomic chapter is mind-bending, but i think i had gone over it.. thanks for the comment

Answer (score 2):

The standard does not define memory fences in terms of how operations are ordered around them.
It defines how a release fence (or operation) *synchronizes with* an acquire fence (or operation) when the right conditions are met.

In your example, if an acquire operation observes the value stored by `y`, it is guaranteed that it also observes the value stored by `x`.
Under those conditions, the store to `x` is ordered before the store to `y`.

Other than that, it is hard to speculate how fences impose ordering since a lot can happen under the *as-if* rule.

Comment: Possibly naive question, but in the code shown, is it possible that an acquire operation could read the (old/undefined) value of `y` (since the `.store` comes after the `memory_order_release`)?

Comment: Yes, that is possible and if it happens, there are no guarantees as to what value `x.load` will return. Fences order operations, they don't wait for each other (like a mutex).